# La forma “[nome proprio] & Co.” regge sempre il singolare?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, agreement

Ho notato sulla confezione dei biscotti che accompagnano la mia colazione la scritta “[nome del biscotto] & Co. presenta i [altro nome di biscotto]”. Mi suona un po' male, forse perché sembra diverso dalla tipica denominazione delle ditte (“ACME & Co.” vorrebbe sicuramente il singolare). È tanto diverso il caso?

Comment: Non capisco: "[nome del biscotto] & Co." è il soggetto e "presenta" è il verbo di una frase?

Comment: @charo esattamente. [altro nome di biscotto] è complemento oggetto.

Comment: E quello che ti sembra strano è che tu ti aspetterebbe il verbo in plurale?

Answer (score 2):

Credo si usi il singolare perché il soggetto va inteso come "l'azienda", "& Co." sta solo ad indicare la partnership con altri associati, ma il soggetto è comunque l'azienda stessa.

EDIT:
Comunque dipende sempre dal nome della società/prodotto, perché i biscotti (stando al tuo esempio) spesso hanno un nome al plurale, quindi in quel caso l'uso del verbo al singolare sarebbe decisamente sbagliato.

Comment: Sono dello stesso avviso ma, se ho ben capito l'esempio portato dall'OP, lì non c'è il vero nome di un'azienda esistente bensì è una mezza spiritosaggine in cui è come se si supponesse che fossero i biscotti a parlare. Giusto, @Agos? Se è così, in effetti suona un po' più strano perché la frase è analoga a “Biscotto1 e gli altri biscotti esistenti presenta BiscottiNuovi”.

Comment: Mi piacerebbe sapere il nome del biscotto a questo punto, perché spesso sono al plurale e quindi suonerebbe strano anche a me l'uso del singolare in quel contesto.

Comment: +1 per essere riuscito a rispondere ad una domanda che, dopo averla letta tre volte, io ancora non la capisco.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider «...io ancora non capisco».